# Angular router link in bootstrap navbar

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-router, angular5

Hi my link is not showing up as tab (using Bootstrap 4 and Angular 5). I only get a plain link. This got to very simple but this is first time with bootstrap...
Thanks a lot!

```
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" routerLinkActive="active">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/legalTerms']">Legal Terms</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Try following the example at the top of https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/.

Based on your code it looks like you are using a custom `nav` component. I'd try at least the basic Bootstrap styling to ensure that works before venturing that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like some of your classes are for Bootstrap 3.

Here's the right way to do a tab nav:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works although this is not the way I intended to use Bootstrap. I have "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2" in package.json and  in angular.cli.json I have       `"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
        "styles.scss"
      ]`   so then I think I should not have to invoke the cdn as I hope the component scss file will get that from the global.scss file - but something is broken as style is gone if I remove the link to the cdn.

Comment: You should do a new question for that problem. (I don't really know much about Angular)